# Pgfplots - automatically distinguish multiple plots in one figure

Tags: pgfplots, plot, gnuplot

I'm writing some app, which generates a TeX code. My program creates variable number of plots and I'd like to use visualize them using `pgfplots`.

In the old version of this app (not created by me), plots are generated with `gnuplot` and they look like this:

[image]

In contrast, my plot is looking like this now:

[image]

**The first problem** is, it appears, that `pgfplots` automatically use lesser number of colors for plots that `gnuplot`, so when I add more plots to the picture, it just keeps switching between blue, red and black, solid, dashed etc. The problem is, when we have multiple plots, just 3 colors make them undifferentiable.

On the other hand, `gnuplot` seems to have a very nice ability to automatically differentiate them visually from each other.

Is there any way to get similar behavior with `pgfplots`? I can't set the color of each plot manually, because I simply don't know, how many of the will be there - app must work for arbitrary number of plots.

**The second problem** is the position of the plot itself in the paper. `tikzpicture` tends to have a huge indent from the left side of the paper and I'm not able to align it to the left.

[image]

Because of the size of plots I really need to force this position to use most of the paper for the plot.

Is there any way how to do it?

---

#### My code

```
\begin{document}

\flushleft
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, remember picture,overlay]
\begin{axis}[
title={ TEST graf },
xlabel={ Number of samples },
ylabel={ Power[W] },
legend pos=outer north east,
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
no markers,
width=18cm,
anchor=north west
]
\addplot table [x=ind, y=val, col sep=comma] {data0.csv};
\addplot table [x=ind, y=val, col sep=comma] {data1.csv};
\addplot table [x=ind, y=val, col sep=comma] {data2.csv};
\addplot table [x=ind, y=val, col sep=comma] {data3.csv};
\legend{ 0,1,2,3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

#### 1st Attempt

After adding `cycle list name = color list`, removing `anchor = north east` and wrapping my `tikzpicture` into `adjustbox` environment with options `valign=t, center` my code looks like this:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t, center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
title={ TEST graf },
xlabel={ Number of samples },
ylabel={ Power[W] },
legend pos=outer north east,
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
no markers,
width=24cm,
height=15cm,
cycle list name = color list
]
\addplot table [x=ind, y=val, col sep=comma] {data0.csv};
\addplot table [x=ind, y=val, col sep=comma] {data1.csv};
\addplot table [x=ind, y=val, col sep=comma] {data2.csv};
\addplot table [x=ind, y=val, col sep=comma] {data3.csv};
\legend{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{adjustbox}
```

And the plot is much better:

[image]

**The only remaining problem** is, that `valign` option is not working - the picture is not on the top of the page. What am I doing wrong this time?

Comment: For the colors, have a look at `cycle list`s in the manual, see section 4.7.7
Cycle Lists – Options Controlling Line Styles. Regarding the horizontal alignment of the plot, I'm guessing this has nothing to with `tikzpicture`, but that your text block is narrower than 18cm (the width of your `axis`), so it sticks into the right margin. To get around that you can use the techniques in [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582) or [How can I center a too wide table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435)

Comment: Also if you are not doing some custom placement or later referral remove `remember picture,overlay` from the picture options

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you very much! My only remaining problem is now, that vertical align doesn't work with `adjustbox` - could you, please have a look at it? (description of the problem was added into the question)

Comment: You've misunderstood what `valign` does, it just sets the "anchor" of the box  on the baseline, it's not relative to the page. Quick hack, try adding `\vspace*{-3cm}` just before the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: ... but if the only thing in your document is this one figure, remove the `adjustbox` stuff, and switch to using `\documentclass{standalone}`. That will give you a page that is the size of the `tikzpicture`, without needing to adjust anything.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I know about `standalone`, but it's not going to be the only thing in my document, so I was looking for other solution. `\vspace*{-3cm}` works great, thanks again! And the last thing I noticed is, that when I make height of my picture bigger than 11cm, it goes automatically to the next page. How can I suppress that behavior? And please, add your comments into one answer, so I could accept it. This information definitely deserves it :-)

Comment: I think the approach in my answer solves the skip-to-next-page-problem. There is still a problem with the page number though (see your last screenshot).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think, the page number is ok - number 2 in my last screenshot is the consequence of the skip-to-next-page problem :-)

Comment: I meant that if your figure is too high the page number could be printed inside the figure. But perhaps that's not a problem when moving the figure up.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. With your code now it's ok - the whole figure is above the number. And the figure is not going to be larger than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors, markers and line styles used by `pgfplots` are defined in so called *cycle lists*. There are several such defined already, see the `pgfplots` manual section 4.7.7 *Cycle Lists – Options Controlling Line Styles*. If none of the existing ones are satisfactory, you can define your own cycle lists, see my answer to [pgfplots adding unwanted dashed lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310858/pgfplots-adding-unwanted-dashed-lines/310874#310874) for one example.

There are a couple of options for centering the figure horizontally and vertically. For horizontal centering you could use the trick in [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth): `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{...}`. To center it vertically one could add negative vertical space with `\vspace*{-3cm}`, but alternatively one can put everything in a `minipage` with a specified height, i.e. `\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight]{\textwidth} ...`

Another option is to add `\usepackage{adjustbox}`, and use `\begin{adjustbox}{center,set height=\textheight} ... \end{adjustbox}` around the figure. Both are demonstrated below, though they give slightly different vertical alignment (not sure why, at the moment).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight]{\textwidth}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={ TEST graf },
xlabel={ Number of samples },
ylabel={ Power[W] },
legend pos=outer north east,
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
no markers,
width=24cm,
height=15cm,
cycle list name = color list
]
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\legend{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}

\begin{adjustbox}{center,set height=\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={ TEST graf },
xlabel={ Number of samples },
ylabel={ Power[W] },
legend pos=outer north east,
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
no markers,
width=24cm,
height=15cm,
cycle list name = color list
]
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\legend{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```